# Symfony .htaccess adding rule for app_MYNAME.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

i want to add another app_MYNAME.php in the web folder. 
This file is nearly identical to the app.php.
The only difference is this entry:

`$kernel = new AppKernel('MYKERNELNAME', false);`

I want to load different configuration files with these method.

When i type in the browser:

`domain.de/app_MYNAME.php/VALUE`

all is fine.

Now i want to hide the `app_MYNAME.php`. The Result should look like:

`domain.de/VALUE`

The second step is the redirecting. When someone type in the browser:

`domain.de/MYNAME/VALUE`

it should be redirected to:

`domain.de/app_MYNAME.php/VALUE`

I only get a `404` or a `misconfigured` message.

At the end i need 3 app_MYNAME.php files (app_MYNAME1.php, app_MYNAME2.php, app_MYNAME3.php).

I hope someone could explain me, what to put in the .htaccess file.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a configuration that looks like this in your *.htaccess* file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # ... Your other stuff

    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_MYNAME.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, make sure that your nginx/apache host file is pointing to the web directory of your Symfony project.

Comment: Hello MeuhMeuh,

when i put in your RewriteRule i've got following error message:
`Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

The apache is pointing to the web directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_MYNAME.php [QSA,L]
```

Maybe all app.php could convert to app_MYNAME.php in your htaccess

Comment: Doesn't work,

i want to hide the `app_MYNAME.php` in the URI and i don't want that all have the same name.